# p:datePicker dateSelect event on empty dates

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datepicker

I have two `p:datePicker` and they work fine:

```
<p:outputLabel for="filterStartDate" value="Start Date:" />
<p:datePicker id="filterStartDate" value="#{historyController.filterStartDate}" timeOnly="true" pattern="HH:mm" converter="#{localTimeConverter}">
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{historyController.filterStartDateSelect}"/>
</p:datePicker>

<p:outputLabel for="filterEndDate" value="End Date:" />
<p:datePicker id="filterEndDate" value="#{historyController.filterEndDate}" timeOnly="true" pattern="HH:mm" converter="#{localTimeConverter}">
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{historyController.filterEndDateSelect}"/>
</p:datePicker>
```

On my **backend** my methods who catch the ajax event are:

```
private LocalTime filterStartDate;
private LocalTime filterEndDate;

public void filterStartDateSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    filterStartDate = ((LocalTime) event.getObject());
}

public void filterEndDateSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    filterEndDate = ((LocalTime) event.getObject());
}
```

This works fine, the problem is when I want to initialize the objects `filterStartDate` and `filterEndDate` to `null`. The ajax event `dateSelect` it's never called when the value is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the ["Ajax Behavior Events" section of the `p:datePicker` documentation](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/datepicker?id=ajax-behavior-events), you'll see that the only explicitly documented event is `dateSelect`. But there is a note:

> In popup mode, `DatePicker` also supports regular ajax behavior events like blur, keyup and more.

So you can add an Ajax listener and handle all the changes and use that to handle `null` values. Or only use the change event to handle all changes, which saves you extra Ajax calls being made to the server.